# Specific urls not opening when trying to deploy rest services using Jersey and tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I was trying to deploy rest services using jersey and tomcat 8.5.
The thing is that the index.html page is opening when i deploy it but when i try to open the a specific url, it sends a message "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." with the http 404 error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">
<display-name>RestApi</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>RestApi</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-
class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>test</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RestApi</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This could be a mapping issue but I have double checked everything.

```
papackage test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String sayHello()
{
    String resource="<?xml version='1.0'?>" + "<hello>xml zzz</hello>";
    return resource;
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String sayHelloJASON()
{
    String resource= null;
    return resource;

}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String sayHelloHTML()
{
    String resource= "<h1>html zzzz</h1>";
    return resource;

}

}
```

Again, The index page opens by default when i launch it. But when i try accessing http://localhost:8080/RestApi/rest/hello, i get a 404 error(The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one e)

Comment: Could you try `http://localhost:8080/rest/hello` ?

Comment: tried /rest/hello..doesnt work

Comment: How do you call your resource? Is the `Accept` header of your client set to one of the media types you're producing? What is the version of Jersey you are using?

Answer (score 0):

As per web.xml, You need to access it like 
http://localhost:8080/warname/rest/hello

Comment: Thats exactly how im doing it..followed all the steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQSat1cKMo ..yet it works for them..but not for me